# Reusable jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col my-col my-col-blue" id="show1">
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col my-col my-col-red" id="show2>
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
            <div class`enter code here`="col my-col my_nav" id="show3">
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target1" style="display: none">
            <div class="menu col my-col my-col-blue">fist 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target2" style="display: none">
            <div class="col my-col my-col-red">fist 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target3" style="display: none">
            <div class="col my-col my_nav">fist 3</div>
        </div>
```

How do I get the right id when id(show1) is clicked so it can toggle(target1). I am able to it as below and It works but I want to create a reusable function. I could do my way but I would need 3 different functions. thanks

ps. when id(show1) is clicked, id(target1) toggle (display).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#show1").click(function() {
           $("#target1").toggle();
      })
 })
```

Comment: You cannot repeat ids.  So your targets are not valid html

Comment: Otherwise, if you gave each target a unique id, you could give each of your columns a data-target `<div class="col my-col my-col-blue" id="show1" data-target="target1">` so it knows which to find and toggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your IDS, gave each heading a class and used data-target to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav-link").on("click",function() {
           $($(this).data("target")).toggle();
      })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div data-target="#target1" class="col my-col my-col-blue nav-link" id="show1">
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
            <div data-target="#target2" class="col my-col my-col-red nav-link" id="show2">
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
            <div data-target="#target3" class="col my-col my_nav nav-link" id="show3">
                <h3>something</h3>
                <p>Lorem error ullam?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target1" style="display: none">
            <div class="menu col my-col my-col-blue">fist 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target2" style="display: none">
            <div class="col my-col my-col-red">fist 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="target3" style="display: none">
            <div class="col my-col my_nav">fist 3</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `data-target` is a custom attribute. It can be anything you wish as long as it starts with `data-` Personally I would use `data-target-selector` because it is more clear what it represents. Alternatively `data-target-id` and concatenate the hash (#) in your method.

Comment: @Marie I add the hash to the data attributes as I work with different plugins that sometimes use IDs and others use classes so putting it in the attribute makes it simpler for me and I feel its cleaner code.